# How can I use arrays and JS to replace classes in a html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an interaction that replaces an element class with the next class in the array when the link is clicked. How can I do that?

Html

```
<a id="text" href="#">Change weights</a>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Javascript

```
var weights = ["jHairline", "jThin", "jLight", "jRegular", "jMedium"];

$('text').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  $("h1").each("weights");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *replaces an element class with the next class*? `h1` hasn't any class. However what class name you want to replaced?

Comment: This looks strange when you use jQuery: `document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('click'`. Why not just `$('#text').click(...)`?

Comment: Do you need [this](https://jsfiddle.net/grzr60qr/)?

Comment: @Satpal yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can something like

```
$(function() {
    var weights = ["jHairline", "jThin", "jLight", "jRegular", "jMedium"];
    //Variable to store the current class being pointed   
    var currentIndex = 0;

    //Bind click handler
    $('#text').on('click', function(e) {
        //Removes all classes and a
        $("h1").removeClass().addClass(weights[currentIndex]);

        //Reset to 0, if its last index
        if (currentIndex == weights.length)
            currentIndex = 0;
        else
            currentIndex++;

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/grzr60qr/1/)

Comment: This is it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate all `h1` element and set relevant class to it. Use [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to do this work.

```js
var weights = ["jHairline", "jThin", "jLight", "jRegular", "jMedium"];
$("#text").click(function(){
    $("h1").removeClass().addClass(function(i){
        return weights[i];
    });
});
```

```css
.jHairline, .jThin, .jLight {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="text" href="#">Change weights</a>
<h1>Hello world</h1> 
<h1>Foo bar</h1> 
<h1>Baz bat</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't really get your jquery, but you can do that :
     $('.yourElement').addClass('ClasstoAdd').removeClass('ClassToRemove');

Comment: This is not what I am looking for but its very useful to know. Thank you.